# How to click Hcaptcha checkbox with python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, captcha

I have the HTML of the hcaptcha checkbox as follows:

> `<div id="checkbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-checked="false" role="checkbox" tabindex="0" aria-live="assertive" aria-labelledby="a11y-label" style="position: absolute; width: 28px; height: 28px; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(145, 145, 145); border-radius: 4px; background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250); top: 0px; left: 0px;"></div>`

[image]

I tried with the following command but no success:

```
check = driver.find_element_by_id("checkbox")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",check)
```

it returns with error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

Some commands like the following don't work either:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="checkbox"]').click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div/div[1]/div[1]/div"))).click()
```

This link: https://gleam.io/gIxR1/cyball-x-ancient8-20-common-packs-cyblocs-1000-usdt-social-giveaways

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you share page url

Comment: https://gleam.io/gIxR1/cyball-x-ancient8-20-common-packs-cyblocs-1000-usdt-social-giveaways

Comment: How do I navigate to that check box ?

Comment: you need to connect to twitter and click on task follow twitter

Comment: probably check for the iframe since most of the captcha loaded with iframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the captcha load in the iframe. so first you have to switch to iframe then locate the captcha

```
iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("IFRAME_XPATH_HERE")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

now you can locate the check box

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="checkbox"]').click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div/div[1]/div[1]/div"))).click()
```

Comment: I fixed it about 1 day ago, your answer is correct, I also have to switch to the frame to be able to click the checkbox. Thank you